# Passing Real Time update to Stripe Checkout Amount

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, pusher

I am trying to implement a variable price in the Stripe Checkout UI that will be updated by Pusher.

I begin by assigning the Pusher message to a global variable called **price**.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var pusher = new Pusher('7a5433c6fc39502a4a02');
      var channel = pusher.subscribe('the_channel');
      var price
      channel.bind('the_event', function(data) {
      price = data.message
      });
  </script>
```

If I assign **price** to data-amount, I am then confronted with two problems:

1- process-wise, the field would be empty by default, populating only when Pusher sends a message.

2- syntax-wise, the variable currently does not even render the message when pushed

```
<%= form_tag charges_path, class: 'stripeform' do %>
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
            data-amount= <%= @price %>
    </script>
<% end %>
```

What to do?

Answer (score 4):

What I'd recommend doing is setting a default value for `@price` in your Rails controller.

Then following the docs over at Stripe you can use something like this to create your button with a variable price. Bear in mind that as the Stripe docs say, you'll still have to create the charge with the correct amount on

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<div id="price-display">$<%= @price %></div>
<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>

<script>
  var price = parseInt("<%= @price %>");

  var pusher = new Pusher('7a5433c6fc39502a4a02');
  var channel = pusher.subscribe('the_channel');
  channel.bind('the_event', function(data) {
    price = parseInt(data.message);
    document.getElementById('price-display').innerHTML = "$" + data.message;
  });

  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: "<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>",
    image: '/square-image.png',
    token: function(token) {
      // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
      // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
    }
  });

  $('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      name: 'Demo Site',
      description: '2 widgets',
      amount: price
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
</script>
```

See here for more Stripe-related info: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Comment: Can I split this into two <script>'s?

Comment: I don't see why not. Give it a go :)